# Objective-C method not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, header

I have a header file with a method called

```
-(NSString*)parsePureTextFromHTML:(NSURL*):URL
```

and in my mainViewController I call the method

```
NSURL* URL = (some url goes here)

NSString* string = [parser parsePureTextFromHTML:URL]
```

and for some reason it is as if the method never gets called.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the compiler give you any warnings? Especially for the line that reads `NSString* string = [parser parsePureTextFromHTML:URL]`?

Answer (score 5):

it should be `-(NSString*)parsePureTextFromHTML:(NSURL*)URL` (remove last `:`)

Comment: that was a typo on the website, that is not actually in my code

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, Do you have an implementation to that header file?

Comment: yes, it the method is clearly written that returns an NSString*

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that `parser` is nil.

Comment: parser is what I called the instance of my header file

Comment: @Keil Kelly - The class is named `parser` with a lowercase `p`? In that case if you want to use a class method switch the `-(NSStr…` to `+(NSStr…`.

Comment: I would think (in fact, I'm positive) that if "parser" is really a class name then executing that call would result in a "unrecognized selector" abort message.

Comment: the Header file is HTMLParser.h and the imp is HTMLParser.m so in my mainviewcontroller.h i have  #import "HTMLParser.h" and HTMLParser* parser;

Comment: Rephrasing: @Keil Kelly - did you do a `parser = [[ParserClass alloc] init];` somewhere?